# Normalization using Numpy vs hard coded

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

```
import numpy as np
import math

def normalize(array):
    mean = sum(array) / len(array)
    deviation = [(float(element) - mean)**2 for element in array]
    std = math.sqrt(sum(deviation) / len(array))
    normalized = [(float(element) - mean)/std for element in array]

    numpy_normalized = (array - np.mean(array)) / np.std(array)

    print normalized
    print numpy_normalized
    print ""

normalize([2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9])
normalize([1, 2])
normalize(range(5))
```

Outputs:

```
[-1.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
[-1.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5  0.   0.   1.   2. ]

[0.0, 1.414213562373095]
[-1.  1.]

[-1.414213562373095, -0.7071067811865475, 0.0, 0.7071067811865475, 1.414213562373095]
[-1.41421356 -0.70710678  0.          0.70710678  1.41421356]
```

Can someone explain to me why this code behaves differently in the second example, but similarly in the other two examples?

Did I do anything wrong in the hard coded example? What does NumPy do to end up with [-1, 1]?

Comment: How is the last example different from the first? In both cases, you've got the same (or very close) numbers, just printing with different numbers of decimal places (and of course with commas between them vs. without).

Comment: Ah, sorry. I meant the other way around, only the [1, 2] example is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [seaotternerd explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30147994/908494), you're using integers. And in Python 2 (unless you `from __future__ import division`), dividing an integer by an integer gives you an integer.

So, why aren't all three wrong? Well, look at the values. In the first one, the sum is 40 and the len is 8, and 40 / 8 = 5. And in the third one, 10 / 5 = 2. But in the second one, 3 / 2 = 1.5. Which is why only that one gets the wrong answer when you do integer division.

So, why doesn't NumPy also get the second one wrong? NumPy doesn't treat an array of integers as floats, it treats them as integers—`print np.array(array).dtype` and you'll see `int64`. However, as the docs for [`np.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) explain, "float64 intermediate and return values are used for integer inputs". And, although I don't know this for sure, I'd guess they designed it that way specifically to avoid problems like this.

---

As a side note, if you're interested in taking the mean of floats, there are other problems with just using `sum` / `div`. For example, the mean of `[1, 2, 1e200, -1e200]` really ought to be 0.75, but if you just do `sum` / `div`, you're going to get `0`. (Why? Well, `1 + 2 + 1e200 == 1e200`.) You may want to look at a simple stats library, even if you're not using NumPy, to avoid all these problems. In Python 3 (which would have avoided your problem in the first place), there's one in the stdlib, called `statistics`; in Python 2, you'll have to go to PyPI.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't converting the numbers in the array to floats when calculating the mean. This isn't a problem for your second or third inputs, because they happen to work out neatly (as explained by @abarnert), but since the second input does not, and is composed exclusively of ints, you end up calculating the mean as 1 when it should be 1.5. This propagates through, resulting in your discrepancy with the results of using NumPy's functions.

If you replace the line where you calculate the mean with this, which forces Python to use float division:

```
mean = sum(array) / float(len(array))
```

you will ultimately get [-1, 1] as a result for the second set of inputs, just like NumPy.

Comment: Or, if you think `int / int` should just return a `float`, you can upgrade to Python 3 or `from __future__ import division` and then the code works as written. :)

Comment: Anyway, the core problem is right, but the explanation is wrong—he's using integers in all three examples, not just the broken one, and he's even using them in his NumPy code.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're totally right. I was somehow looking at the outputs instead of the inputs for the first and third examples.